# Ethereum Classic (ETC) And The DAO Holders - Will The White Hat Hackers Return The DAO Funds?

Tags: ether, the-dao, hardforks, ethereum-classic

As a DAO token holder I'm wondering if the DAO White Hat Hackers will return the funds to the DAO token holders on the Ethereum Classic chain?

I'm 100% for the Ethereum forked chain, but I can't turn my back on free money...

Thanks